# Offline sync with Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb, offlineapps

I have a Xamarin.Forms app using Azure Cosmos DB (DocumentDB) and I'd like to implement offline synchronization.

Is it possible? Can we use Mobile App Services with DocDB?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no locally-installable version of Cosmos DB (aside from the dev/test emulator), so I suspect you'll need to whip up something on your own.

Comment: @DavidMakogon The Azure Mobile Apps SDK will use local storage for Offline Data Synchronization on the device (either iOS Core Data or SQLite), and then the back-end database for Easy Tables / Table API is backed by either Azure SQL Database or Storage.

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann - Right - I was thinking specifically of the SQL API support the OP was looking for - there's currently no built-in way of storing locally and then backing with Cosmos DB SQL (DocumentDB).

Comment: Then I suppose it is pointless to use DocDB with Xamarin Forms. You lose a lot of responsiveness and stuffs without Offline Sync...

Comment: Possible? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/00b2ea1a-be69-40bd-b290-1340d80846f4/mobile-services-offline-sync-with-documentdb?forum=azuremobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Offline Data Synchronization feature of Azure Mobile Apps, you need to use the Easy Tables support of the service which requires a back-end database with either Azure SQL Database or Storage. It currently does not support using Cosmos DB as the back-end database for Azure Mobile Apps Easy Tables / Table API support.

Comment: It seems, it is possible? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/00b2ea1a-be69-40bd-b290-1340d80846f4/mobile-services-offline-sync-with-documentdb?forum=azuremobile